# Improving the performance of rows.Scan() in Go

Tags: performance, sqlite, go, database-performance

I have a very simple query that returns a couple thousand rows with only two columns:

```
SELECT "id", "value" FROM "table" LIMIT 10000;
```

After issuing [`sql.Query()`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Stmt.Query), I traverse the result set with the following code:

```
data := map[uint8]string{}

for rows.Next() {
    var (
        id     uint8
        value  string
    )

    if error := rows.Scan(&id, &value); error == nil {
        data[id] = value
    }
}
```

If I run the exact same query directly on the database, I get all results back within a couple of milliseconds, but the Go code takes far longer complete, **sometimes almost 10 seconds**!

I started commenting out several parts of the code and it seems that [`rows.Scan()`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) is the culprit.

> Scan copies the columns in the current row into the values pointed at
>   by dest.
>
> If an argument has type *[]byte, Scan saves in that argument a copy of
>   the corresponding data. The copy is owned by the caller and can be
>   modified and held indefinitely. The copy can be avoided by using an
>   argument of type *RawBytes instead; see the documentation for RawBytes
>   for restrictions on its use. If an argument has type *interface{},
>   Scan copies the value provided by the underlying driver without
>   conversion. If the value is of type []byte, a copy is made and the
>   caller owns the result.

Can any expect any speed improvement if I use `*[]byte`, `*RawBytes` or `*interface{}` instead?

Looking at [the code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go?s=40007:40054#L1541), it looks like the [`convertAssign()` function](http://golang.org/src/pkg/database/sql/convert.go#L82) is doing a lot of stuff that isn't necessary for this particular query. So my question is: how can I make the `Scan` process faster?

I thought about overloading the function to expect predetermined types, but that isn't possible in Go...

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened when you tried `*[]byte`, `*RawBytes` and `*interface{}`?

Comment: @peterSO: I was reading the documentation and data from `*RawBytes` seems to go away whenever you call `rows.Next()`. I haven't tried the other two, I was merely asking if it would help with anything. If you look at the `convertAssign` source code (linked in the answer), the `uint8` type still requires going thru reflection I think.

Comment: Did you try using the profiler to help narrow it down?

Comment: @DanielWilliams: No, I'm quite new to Go, could you link me to a tutorial or documentation that explains how to use the profiler?

Comment: Here's a good post about it http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Can you try other drives and check the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can use `RawBytes` instead and `rows.Scan()` will avoid memory allocation/copying

About `convertAssign()` function - yes, its not optimal in Go 1.2, 
but they make significant improvements in 1.3:
- http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=7086
- Lock-less implementation for sync.Pool

I have some example of `RawBytes` usage - https://gist.github.com/yvasiyarov/9911956

This code read data from MySQL table, make some processing and write it to CSV files.
Last night it takes 1 minute 24 seconds to generate 4GB of CSV data(about 30 million rows)

so I'm pretty sure what problem is outside of go code: even worse possible usage of `rows.Scan()` can not give you 10 seconds delay.

Comment: The reason was a cold database and a busy disk, thanks for answering.